# How can I simulate <div></div> on enter keypress, contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, caret

In a Content Editable div, when you press enter, it creates another div and puts the text inside it.

I need a way to simulate that enter, because if I use `<br>` I loose the caret position.

What I have by now:

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) pasteHtmlAtCaret("<div>");
if (e.keyCode != 13) document.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
```

The problem with this is that the caret doesn't get inside the div

Comment: Your saying you what to append another div as a child node? Content editable div? Does this div contain a textarea?

Comment: No, it doesn't contain a textarea but yes, I want to do that and write text inside the child node, just like the contenteditable does

Comment: Can you post your code as a jsfiddle? That'll make it easier to figure out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3eafrpwe/ , For some rason in JsFiddle the divs in the contentEditable work, but for our document, it doesn't, and we are trying to reproduce the same thing the contenteditable does

Comment: The CSS is missing, so your elements look invisible.

Comment: Just a quick note, you can change the position of the caret programatically   (check [this out](https://github.com/wlritchi/jCaret)).

Comment: I ended up doing everything manually by now lok, but thanks a lot, I had find out CaretJS but that one hadn't support for contenteditable.